# Validate checkbox that which are required

Tags: angularjs, validation, checkbox

I'd like to create terms and conditions form in my angularjs project.

From multiple checkboxes only several are required, and I'd like to enable submit button, only when all required checkboxes are checked.

Here is my checkboxes:

```
<label class="agreement-label control-label required">Zgoda</label>
<input class="agreements ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="agreement_1" name="agreement" required="" ng-model="client.agreement[0]" type="checkbox">

<label class="agreement-label control-label">Zgoda 2</label>
<input class="agreements ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" id="agreement_2" name="agreement" ng-model="client.agreement[1]" type="checkbox">

<label class="agreement-label control-label">Zgoda 4</label>
<input class="agreements ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" id="agreement_5" name="agreement" ng-model="client.agreement[4]" type="checkbox">

<label class="agreement-label control-label required">Zgoda 5</label>
<input class="agreements ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="agreement_6" name="agreement" required="" ng-model="client.agreement[5]" type="checkbox">

<button class="btn btn-success" id="ticketFormSubmit" ng-disabled="isAgreementsInvalid()" ng-click="changeButtonValue()" type="submit" disabled="disabled">Zapisz</button>
```

And in my angular controller:

```
$scope.isAgreementsInvalid = function() {
    return $scope.ticketForm.agreement.$invalid;
}
```

The problem is, only last required checkbox is validating.

Comment: change the `name` attribute of all the checkbox. Means not repeat the `name` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this, but **ng-init** is necessary for this solution. **name will not be required** for this solution.:-

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.isAllChecked = false;
  $scope.checkValid = function() {
    $scope.isAllChecked = true
    angular.forEach($scope.client.agreement, function(value) {
      if (!value) {
        $scope.isAllChecked = false;
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form name="ticketForm">
      <label class="agreement-label control-label required">Zgoda</label>
      <input ng-init="client.agreement[0] = false;" class="agreements" id="agreement_1" required ng-model="client.agreement[0]" type="checkbox" ng-click="checkValid()">

      <label class="agreement-label control-label">Zgoda 2</label>
      <input ng-init="client.agreement[1] = false;" class="agreements" id="agreement_2" required ng-model="client.agreement[1]" type="checkbox" ng-click="checkValid()">


      <button class="btn btn-success" id="ticketFormSubmit" ng-disabled="!isAllChecked" ng-click="submitFunction()" type="submit" disabled="disabled">Zapisz</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ok, but could it be done with function in controller and "foreach" by all checkboxes?

Comment: @gawellus update the answer according to requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this slightly more succinctly by using some():

```
$scope.isAgreementsInvalid = function() {
  return $scope.ticketForm.agreement.some((item) => item.$invalid);
}
```